# Is there a tutorial like this on Flash Actionscript 3? (Scrolling Text Using Buttons In Flash)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Is there a tutorial for flash actionscript 3 like this one, the easiest way as much as possible. thanks!

(Scrolling Text Using Buttons In Flash)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK-uemUM0JY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scrollbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click);
function click(e:MouseEvent){
    myText.scrollV += 1;
    // or myText.scrollV -= 1;
}
```